# Trying to run Open JML in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jml

I am trying to install JML and was successful after trying various eclipse distributions
but I am getting this error:
(using eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-win32)
the error appears when I use menu: JML > Static Check (ESC)

**The executeable for prover is not specified - use -exec or define an openjml.prover**
Please provide some help

[Image Link](http://i60.tinypic.com/28be0co.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after putting more effort I resolved it,

actually I had to download a prover executeable file for windows OS
then create folder and place the exe in it (C:\Java\CVC4)
then in Eclipse

Window > Preferences > JML > JML Solver > CVC Browser button to locate the
above cvc4 executeable path C:\Program Files\Java\cvc4\cvc4-1.3-win32-opt.exe
After that it was working fine